# Transform a list of maps in Elixir

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I have a list of maps, that I get from querying my database.It has a datetime field that I want to transform into another list of maps where the datetime field is transformed to it's corresponding epoch value.

What i have:

```
[
  %{
    m_id: 267,
    end: #DateTime<2020-03-07 17:30:00Z>,
    start: #DateTime<2020-03-07 14:30:00Z>,
    type: "normal",
    s_name: "smum",
    w_id: 256
  },
  %{
    m_id: 267,
    end: #DateTime<2020-03-07 07:30:00Z>,
    start: #DateTime<2020-03-07 04:30:00Z>,
    type: "normal",
    s_name: "smum",
    w_id: 256
  }
]
```

What i want to transform it to:

```
[
  %{
    m_id: 267,
    end: 12356789, #some epoch value for eg
    start: 12367576, #some epoch value for eg
    type: "normal",
    s_name: "smum",
    w_id: 256
  },
  %{
    m_id: 267,
    end: 12334567, #some epoch value for eg
    start: 12354767, #some epoch value for eg
    type: "normal",
    s_name: "smum",
    w_id: 256
  }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To transform a single map, you can do

```
%{map | end: DateTime.to_unix(map.end), start: DateTime.to_unix(map.start) }
```

So just `Enum.map` over the list to apply this to all list members:

```
Enum.map(list, fn map -> %{map | end: DateTime.to_unix(map.end), start: DateTime.to_unix(map.start) } end)
```

(I suspected there may be a problem using the map update syntax here because `end` is a reserved word, but I tested in https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-elixir-online/ and it works.)

Comment: `[end: 42]` keyword is absolutely equal to `[{:end, 42}]` list containing a single tuple, so I doubt it might interfere with `end` syntactic sugar (also, _elixir_ has _zero_ keywords.)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I should have said "reserved word" since Elixir has its own meaning for "keyword" :) And it does have those according to https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/pages/Syntax%20Reference.md#reserved-words. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_word says "a closely related and often conflated notion is a keyword", I am not sure how generally accepted this distinction is.

Comment: Yes, I tend to agree, although the whole [tag:elixir] syntax is based on macros, but some macros have especial meaning and handled by compiler explicitly, so they might have been treated as reserved words, although technically they are still macros, but ... :)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin not really macros, these are "special forms" as compiler need to know about them and treat them in "their own special way". If these would be "the same as macros" then `if` in "classic" languages would be such macro as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with [`Kernel.SpecialForms.for/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#for/1) comprehension.

```rb
for %{start: s, end: e} = map <- list do
  %{map | start: DateTime.to_unix(s), end: DateTime.to_unix(e)}
end
```

---

It’s slightly different from `Enum.map/2` solution, because it would discard those elements *not* having either `start` or `end` keys. To handle those properly, one should use `Map.update/4` wisely.